# How to delete angular firebase storage entry?

Tags: angular

I'm using firestorage for storing images.

I'm being able to store images.

But I'm not being able to delete a particular directory or folder.

The following is my implementation

```
  constructor(
    private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore,
    private angularFireStorage: AngularFireStorage
  )
```

```
deleteItemDirectory(id) {
    
    const storageRef = `uploads/items/${id}`;
    this.angularFirestore
      .collection('items')
      .doc(id)
      .delete()
      .then(() => {
        this.angularFireStorage.storage.ref(storageRef).delete()
      });
  }

// where the id refers to the folder
```

I'm, getting the following error when I try to delete a directory.

```
Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseStorageError: {"code_":"storage/object-not-found","message_":"Firebase Storage: Object 'uploads/items' does not exist.","serverResponse_":"{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 404,\n    \"message\": \"Not Found.  Could not delete object\",\n    \"status\": \"DELETE_OBJECT\"\n  }\n}","name_":"FirebaseError"}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are storing image in FireStorage at uploads/items location ?

Comment: try first delete the file in storage and then the document that had information about it

Comment: Yes. I'm storing images.

Comment: I'm being able to delete individual images. or all images. But not being able to delete any folder/directory.

Comment: I've tried both ways... tried deleting the document first then the file itself and reverse...

Comment: The original files database is separate & storage is separate.. so this is not the issue..